# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in

Tags: json, webpack, npm, three.js

Я пытаюсь сделать загрузку сцены из формата `.json` в `three.js`. Но проблема в том, что в `three.js` использование формата `.json` является устаревшим, но тем не менее мне это нужно. Поэтому я начал искать другие пути и нашел [этот репозиторий](https://github.com/omkarap55/three-Legacy-JSON-Loader) который предоставляет эту возможность. Но при попытке собрать проект с `webpack` при подключенном модуле выдается такая ошибка в терминале
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Потом я установил этот модуль `npm i fs`, и появляется та же ошибка в терминале и такая ошибка в консоли браузера
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подключаю в **index.js** модуль так:

```js
const LegacyJSONLoader = require('three-legacyjsonloader');
...
```

````
<br/>**webpack.config.js:**
```javascript
const path = require("path");


module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    }
}
````

**package.json**:

```js
{
  "name": "_____",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "three": "^0.119.1",
    "three-legacyjsonloader": "^1.0.6", // модуль для загрузки *.json в three.js
    "three.interaction": "^0.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
}
```

*P.S. Никаких методов модуля `three-legacyjsonloader` я не использую, лишь подключаю*

Comment: я так понял, что `three-legacyjsonloader` вызывает `fs` модуль, который по умолчанию есть в любой **NodeJS** (на сервере). а Вы рендерите приложение на клиенте, где `fs` нет и, думаю, быть не может.

Comment: @Август но ведь модуль который я пытаюсь подключить должен работать на клиенте

Comment: я не могу сказать точно, но, **скорее всего**, это невозможно, так как у браузера и так очень ограниченный доступ к файловой системе *ПК*. а точнее, его **почти** нет и он запрещен. это сделано исходя от мер безопасности. теоретически, `fs` модуль никак не сможет там работать

Comment: `использование формата .json является устаревшим` откуда инфа? загружайте сколько влезет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

использовал [ObjectLoader()](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/ObjectLoader) для загрузки `.json`

```js
import { ObjectLoader } from "three"

new ObjectLoader("scene.json", function(object) { scene.add(object); } ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте добавить

```
node: {
    fs: "empty"
},
```

в Ваш `webpack.config`